# Magento 2 : How to run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command programatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is there a way to run **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** in a M2 script? or programatically? I have a scenario where in the CSS file is replaced within the admin panel. So I was thinking to automate the running of **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** without going to the terminal and manually running this command. Is there a way to achieve this? It's not only the **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** but also the **bin/magento cache:clean**

Comment: `setup:di:compile` generates php classes and doesn't relate to css. Probably you need `setup:static-content:deploy`. For `setup:di:compile` you can call `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand::run`

Comment: @jonijones updated my question

Comment: In that case, you can use `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand` and `\Magento\Backend\Console\Command\CacheCleanCommand` as dependencies in your code and call `run` method to regenerate static files and clear the cache

Comment: @jonijones I know it's too much can you perhaps add this as answer and show a sample code for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
exec('bin/magento setup:di:compile');
exec('bin/magento cache:clean');
```

should get you what you need

Answer (score 0):

Create Shell script.
 Add **`bin/magento setup:di:compile`** ... command into shell script.

Then you can run this shell script using php file on any specific event on which you want run.

I hope this will help you.